# Time needed to check all possible combinations

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, applications

Suppose we want to find the time needed to write down all possible combinations of 58 characters.

With a string of size n the possible combinations are 58^n.

We pick random characters every time we write down a string. If I write 1000 strings /second how much time will I need to write 50% of the possible strings?

How can we find the time for any percentage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *expected* time needed to write down some fraction of the possible strings, you can use the same argument as in the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) with $58^n$ coupons by adding the expected time to see a new coupon until you reach whatever fraction of the coupons you are aiming for.

Comment: The number of trials will be 58^nlog(58^n) and I write 1 string every 1 millisecond - > total time = 58^nlog(58^n)/1000 correct?

Comment: @MaddyWells The original coupon collector's problem computes the expected time to collect *all* the coupons, but if you only want 50% of them, you need to modify the argument slightly.

Comment: I wanted the 100% from the beginning just because I thought it may have to do something with half-lives that is why I posted 50%.